# Etsy API - ValueError: Could not decode response from Etsy as JSON

Tags: python, etsy

I'm making an app using the Etsy api which gathers transaction data per shop listing. I'm using [this python library](https://pypi.org/project/etsy2/) to make calls to the api.

Here is my full code:

```
from etsy2 import Etsy
from etsy2.oauth import EtsyOAuthHelper, EtsyOAuthClient
import urllib.parse as urlparse
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

api_key = #api_key
shared_secret = #shared_secret

#visit login_url to get temp_oauth_token
login_url, temp_oauth_token_secret = \
    EtsyOAuthHelper.get_request_url_and_token_secret(api_key, shared_secret, permission_scopes)

query = urlparse.urlparse(login_url).query
temp_oauth_token = parse_qs(query)['oauth_token'][0]

#input token here
oauth_token, oauth_token_secret = \
EtsyOAuthHelper.get_oauth_token_via_verifier(api_key, shared_secret, temp_oauth_token, temp_oauth_token_secret, input('Verifier: '))

etsy_oauth = EtsyOAuthClient(client_key = api_key,
                         client_secret = shared_secret,
                         resource_owner_key = oauth_token,
                         resource_owner_secret = oauth_token_secret)

etsy = Etsy(etsy_oauth_client = etsy_oauth)

listings = etsy.findAllListingActive()

etsy.findAllListingTransactions(listing_id=#listing_id)
```

**This is the error I get** when I try to call `findAllListingTransactions` (listing_id and url not shown for privacy):

```
ValueError: Could not decode response from Etsy as JSON: status_code: 404, text: 'Listing not found for listing_id: #listing_id’, url: #url
```

**What I've tried:**

Multiple listing ids.
Changing permission scopes (although [in the api docs](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/reference/receipt) this only requires the `transactions_r` scope which I have. Trying other methods such as `findAllShopReceipts` but that just gives me `'error_messages': ['Access denied']`.

Does anyone have experience with the etsy api to help with this?

Comment: are `listing_id`s you're trying `int`s?

Comment: Yes, otherwise it would throw a 'Bad value' error.